# Hide soft Keyboard on Drawer open - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a `TextField` and a `ModalDrawer` in a compose screen. I would like to close the soft keyboard when the user opens the drawer, but I haven't been able to figure out how. There is no `onOpened` lifecycle event that gets triggered in `ModalDrawer` afaik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the confirmStateChange parameter in rememberDrawerState() and call keyboardController.hide() when the drawerValue becomes DrawerValue.open like this:

```kotlin
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val state = rememberDrawerState(
  initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed,
    confirmStateChange = {
       if (it == DrawerValue.Open) {
           keyboardController?.hide()
       }
       true
    }
)

ModalDrawer(
   drawerState = state,
   ...
) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I do have one caveat though; for anyone reading this answer, `confirmStateChange` lambda expects a `boolean`, so you will need to add `true` at the end of it.

Comment: This is correct! I will update my answer.

Comment: The only problem I see is `confirmStateChange` doesn't get called when you call `show()` or `hide()` on the drawer. It only gets called when the user slides the drawer in or out (or taps on the scrim which dismisses the keyboard). If you call `show()` when a button is pushed, then this won't help.

Comment: ...so, for button press, duplicate the logic and put it in the button's `onClick` as well.